# Adding a vertical tab the the content type form page

Tags: nodes, theming, routes

How can i add a vertical tab to the content type manage form page?

I want to add a vertical tab that has a form like the ones it currently has.  For example: it has menu settings, display settings, etc.  I want to add a tab that ties a theme to a content type.  Can you someone help me out?

Thanks

Comment: not sure, but it has a form template file, which you can edit it, in your admin theme, or you can define a custom template for that in template.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this. Or read about [`hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/7)

```
function mymodule_form_node_type_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
  $default_value =TRUE;// auto_nodetitle_get_setting($form['#node_type']->type);

  $type = $form['#node_type'];
  $form['mymodule'] = array(
    '#type' => 'fieldset',
    '#title' => t('mymodule'),
    '#weight' => 0,
    '#collapsible' => TRUE,
    '#collapsed' => false,
    '#group' => 'additional_settings',
    '#attached' => array(
      'js' => array(drupal_get_path('module', 'menu') . '/menu.admin.js'),
    ),
  );

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add vertical tabs into content type just using [Field Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_group) module.

**Field Group:**

> Fieldgroup will, as the name implies, group fields together. All fieldable entities will have the possibility to add groups to wrap their fields together. Fieldgroup comes with default HTML wrappers like vertical tabs, horizontal tabs, accordions, fieldsets or div wrappers.
>
> The field group project is a follow-up on the field group module in [CCK](https://www.drupal.org/project/cck). The release will only exist for Drupal 7 release and higher, so since the existence of the Fields API in core.
> By moving field group to a separate module, this may open some new perspectives.

Answer (score 0):

`additional_settings` is the magic keyword. Search https://www.drupal.org/project/examples for it and you'll get at least two good examples:

First in [`vertcial_tabs_example.module`](https://api.drupal.org/api/examples/vertical_tabs_example!vertical_tabs_example.module/7) for the basic setup.

Second in [`nodeapi_example.module`](https://api.drupal.org/api/examples/nodeapi_example!nodeapi_example.module/7) and [`nodeapi_example.install`](https://api.drupal.org/api/examples/nodeapi_example!nodeapi_example.install/7) when it comes to saving variables and working with them.